# jquery - get all rows except the first and last

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i want to dynamically add a class to all rows of a table except the first and last row.  how would i do this without assigning a css class to the rows to identify them.  I am getting all but the first row currently with

```
$("#id").find("tr:gt(0)")
```

i need to combine this with `not("tr:last")` somehow maybe?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Drop the `gt()`, as I'd assume it's a tiny bit slower than `:first`.

Use `not()` in conjunction with `:first` and `:last`:

```
$('table#tbl > tbody > tr').not(':first').not(':last').addClass('highlight');
```

Most browsers automatically add an `tbody` element in the table markup if that's missing, that is why the immediate children selector was failing – there were no `<tr>` elements as an immediate children to the `<table>` tag.

I am not 100% sure this is the way all browsers do it, so it would be safer to just add the `<tbody>` manually. Otherwise you need a little sniffing and cannot do it as an one liner:

```
if($('table#tbl > tbody').size() > 0) {
    $('table#tbl > tbody > tr').not(':first').not(':last').addClass('highlight');
} else {
    $('table#tbl > tr').not(':first').not(':last').addClass('highlight');
}
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: this works - unless the last row has a table in it - which is the case.  this is a server control so can't easily be changed. any ideas?

<table id="tbl">
<tr><td>header</td><td>header</td></tr>
<tr><td>one</td><td>one</td></tr>
<tr><td>two</td><td>two</td>
<tr><td colspan="2">

<table border="0">
<tr>
 <td>footer one</td><td>footer two</td><td>footer three</td><td>footer four</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: Sure, use `$('#id > tr')` instead of `$('#id tr')`. That forces the selector to select only the immediate children. This requires that the `#id` element is a `<table>`.

Comment: thanks for the response. with the table html i posted in first comment, `$('#tbl > tr').not(':first').not(':last').addClass("highlight");` for example, does not seem work nor does `$('table#tbl > tr').not(':first').not(':last').addClass("highlight");`

Comment: tatu - i marked this as the answer - thanks for all the help. i had no idea about tbody - i wonder which browsers do this.  seems crazy to have to handle a tag that is not there

Comment: :first is now deprecated. https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
.not(':first').not(':last')
```

Answer (score 16):

why not just this?

```
$('table tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)');
```

works as pure CSS selector as well.

Answer (score 9):

You can combine the `.not()` methods into one by separating the selectors with commas:

```
$('#id tr').not(':first, :last');
$('#id tr:not(:first, :last');
```

Note that the second one is not valid in pure CSS, only as a jQuery selector. For pure CSS you'd have to use @Sumit's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Strange the  suggestions posted did not work, they should all work! BUT...

If it did not work, do it this way.... slightly slower but MUST WORK!!
TRY:

```
$('table#tbl tr').addClass('highlight');
$('table#tbl tr:first-child').removeClass('highlight');
$('table#tbl tr:last-child').removeClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [`.slice()` method](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to remove the first/last elements from the set:

```
$('table tr').slice(1, -1);
```

The [`.slice()` method](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) essentially creates a new jQuery object with a subset of the elements specified in the initial set. In this case, it will exclude the elements with an index of `1` and `-1`, which are the first/last elements respectively.

#### Example:

```js
$('table tr').slice(1, -1).css('background-color', '#f00');
```

```css
table { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

Of course, you can also negate `:first-child`/`:last-child` using `:not()`:

```js
$('table tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)').css('background-color', '#f00');
```

```css
table { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

You can also combine `:nth-child(n+2)` and `:nth-last-child(n+2)`:

```js
$('table tr:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2)').css('background-color', '#f00');
```

```css
table { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Worked for me! Seems easier to use than what the others have proposed.